# Adding parameter to SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to get some data from Excel table using SQL-query inside macros.

My code is:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String


Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With

Value1 = Range("B4").Value ' = 30.10.2020
Value2 = Range("C4").Value ' = 2

'I want to insert Value2 = 2 inside my SQL query
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Page 1$] WHERE Job = Value2 AND DateTime = Value1"
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql) 'but it doesn't work, stops here

Do
   output = output & rs("Name") & ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2) & vbNewLine
   Debug.Print rs(0); ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2)
   rs.Movenext
Loop Until rs.EOF
MsgBox output

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I try using `sql = "SELECT * FROM [Page 1$] WHERE Job = 2"`, I have no errors.

How could I paste `Value2` and `Value1` values inside my SQL-query?

Comment: Change: `sql = "SELECT * FROM [Page 1$] WHERE Job = Value2"` to: `sql = "SELECT * FROM [Page 1$] WHERE Job = " & Value2`

Comment: @Zac, and if i have two or more values?

Comment: @Zac I really like your answer, it's pretty simple

Comment: If you want to add more than 1 value, you could do something like: `sql = "SELECT * FROM [Page 1$] WHERE Job = " & Value1 & Value2`

Comment: no problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim param1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim param2 As New ADODB.Parameter

Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@Value2", Value2, adParamInput)
param1.Value = Range("C4").Value
cmd.Parameters.Append param1

Set param2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@Value1", Value1, adParamInput)
param2.Value = Range("B4").Value
cmd.Parameters.Append param2

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Page 1$] WHERE Job = ? AND DateTime = ?"

    Set rs = .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Use Parameterized Queries as shown in the example above whenever humanly possible. It a) helps securing your application by e.g. proper string escaping and b) converts your variable values/data types to the correct equivalent SQL format.

Comment: @Angelika You can add more parameter

Comment: Yes, but how could I access them? Using index inside cmd?

Comment: Yes you can add how many you want, but you should maintain the order.

Comment: I get compile error on `Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command` User-defined type not defined

Comment: @VigneshKumarA edited my question, I don't understand how to use more than one parameter

Comment: @VigneshKumarA, thank you a lot! But `Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command` still gives an error :(

Comment: I suspect you are getting the error because you haven't added the reference to **ADODB**